# I can’t see custom logs events in DebugView Firebase Analytics ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-analytics

I’m using Xcode 12.5.1, swift 5, firebase 8.8.0

I can see the screen_view logs, user_engagement in the debugView in real time but I can’t see custom logs events.
I don’t know if I sent them correctly, can somebody help me find out please ?

I did put the GoogleService-info file with the right bundleID
I put the FirebaseApp.configure() in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
I did activate the -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled in scheme

Here is the function that I used

```
func logCustomEvent(name: String, category: String, action: String, label: String) {
    Analytics.logEvent(name, parameters: ["eventCategory": category, "eventAction": action, "eventLabel": label])
}
```

```
Analytics.logEvent("event_log_test", parameters: ["params": "value_test"])
```

Thanks for your help

[GoogleService-info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp97I.png)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, because i used Firebase in Pod in others frameworks that i use in my project.
So i had duplicate class firebase.
In my console log i saw :

```
class 'className' is implemented in both Pod
```

For fix it, now i just use Firebase Pod in my main project, and now i can see log event custom